# listreceivedbyaddress - wallet file not specified error

Tags: wallet, address, json-rpc, balance

So to start I have very little experience and this may be a simple answer but I can't find it easily.

I suspect that I am using the wrong thing to achieve what I am trying to do.

I'm parsing out the blocks locally to get transactional information. Then I am trying to take each wallet addr with a transaction and check the current balance.

When I run this code I get this error "('Wallet file not specified (must request wallet RPC through /wallet/ uri-path).',)" which makes me think I am not using the correct method.

If I'm not using the correct method, what should I be using?

```
                received_info = rpc_connection.listreceivedbyaddress(1, False, True, str([output_address]))
                            if received_info:
                                output_file.write(f"  Received by Address Info:\n")
                                for info in received_info:
                                    output_file.write(f"    Address: {info['address']}\n")
                                    output_file.write(f"    Amount Received: {info['amount']} BTC\n")
                                    output_file.write(f"    Confirmations: {info['confirmations']}\n\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`listreceivedbyaddress`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/26.0.0/rpc/wallet/listreceivedbyaddress/) is a wallet RPC, it will only provide data on any addresses that are part of your wallet.

Bitcoin Core does not index balances by addresses outside of its own wallet’s addresses. You could use [`scanblocks`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/26.0.0/rpc/blockchain/scanblocks/) which will need the node to have a `blockfilterindex`, or alternatively [`scantxoutset`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/26.0.0/rpc/blockchain/scantxoutset/). I’m not sure either of these two would be particularly performant, so if you want to scan for a lot of addresses, you may want to look into running an electrum server or block explorer backend such as Esplora.

Comment: gotcha, thanks. So I can't use the blockchain locally as a sort of queryable DB?

I will look into Esplora

Comment: There is an option to run a `txindex`, but there is no address index

Comment: Could I use scanblocks() with the addr as the descriptor?

Comment: Oh, yeah, `scanblocks` would be a better choice. I forgot we have that now. You do need the `blockfilterindex` of course in order for that to be available.